# Reaching CakeRequest object from CakePHP component

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to reach CakeRequest object from my custom component. But I can't. Inside [cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#cakerequest) I found this:

> CakeRequest is the default request object used in CakePHP. It
>   centralizes a number of features for interrogating and interacting
>   with request data. On each request one CakeRequest is created and then
>   passed by reference to the various layers of an application that use
>   request data. By default CakeRequest is assigned to $this->request,
>   and is available in Controller, Views and Helpers. **You can also access
>   it in Components by using the controller reference.**

What it means with controller reference? I tried the following. It works.
But how can I reach CakeRequest without passing an argument **this** to component ?

```
// MyController.php
    public function foo(){
        $this->MyUtil->bar($this);
    }

// MyUtilComponent.php
    function bar(&$controller) {
        $a=$controller->request;
        print_r($a);
    }
```

Comment: I think by 'controller reference' they just mean accessing it like:  `$this->params->someVar` from the controller.  As for how to not pass `$this` maybe you need to mess with `var $uses`?  Dunno - I found Cake to be a great framework to write throwaway code I could not easily reuse.

Comment: This looks like it might be a very good read for you: http://mark-story.com/posts/view/the-cakerequest-object-in-cakephp-2-0

Comment: you are using PHP5. Why are you trying to pass an object by reference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CakePHP Components have an [`initialize`](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/component#method-Componentinitialize) callback that you can use to store a reference to the controller. Add this to your Component class:

```
public function initialize(Controller $controller) {
    $this->controller = $controller;
}
```

Then `bar` can just be:

```
function bar() {
    $a = $this->controller->request;
    print_r($a);
}
```

Comment: almost - `public function initialize(Controller $controller)` to avoid E_STRICT warnings here.

Comment: Thanks for the link @trante, I added it to the answer body.